# Azure active directory registered java spring application returning code instead of token after logging in

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, spring-oauth2

I have registered a java spring application into azure active directory for Microsoft authenticated login. Microsoft login api is supposed to return token to redirect_uri (defined in azure where client browser is redirected after successful login).

Azure provides token attached to the redirect_uri?token={az_token}

but instead i am getting redirect_uri?code={some_code} which is not JWT

expected = [http://127.0.0.1:4200?token={az_token}](http://127.0.0.1:4200?token=%7Baz_token%7D)
getting = [http://127.0.0.1:4200?code={some_code}](http://127.0.0.1:4200?code=%7Bsome_code%7D)

Comment: Hi did you have a chance to look into my answer? Any updates?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to understand the differences between [OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) and [implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow).

For authorization code flow, we should [Request an authorization code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code) and then [Request an access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token) using the auth code. Please note `&response_type=code` in the request. In this case you will get `http://127.0.0.1:4200?code={some_code}`. Then you can use this code to call `/token` endpoint to get the access token.

If you want to get access token from `/authorize` endpoint directly, you should consider implicit grant flow. See [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#getting-access-tokens-silently-in-the-background).

// Line breaks for legibility only

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=token
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read
&response_mode=fragment
&state=12345
&nonce=678910
&prompt=none
&login_hint=myuser@mycompany.com
```

It includes `&response_type=token` in this case, which will return the access token like this: `http://127.0.0.1:4200?token={access_token}`.

Remember that you need to [Enable the implicit flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-spa#enable-the-implicit-flow) in your java spring application.